# How do I pass data from python to html?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to make a webscraper that will get data from coronavirus websites. I have made the scraper I was just curious as to how to pass that data I get to my html code. Here is my python code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

page_url = 'https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html'
uClient = uReq(page_url)
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"callout"})
out_filename = "usacovid_deaths.csv"
headers = "Deaths \n"
Deaths = containers[0].span.text
print(Deaths +"\n")

with open(out_filename, "w") as f: 
    f.write(Deaths + "\n")

f.close()
```

By the way, I know this type of website has been done before but I still want to do it for my own enjoyment. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: could you show the output of `print(Deaths +"\n")` ?

Comment: Yeha it just comes out as the number of deaths as of right now in the terminal.

Comment: You might want to use the csv module. [link to the documntation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Csv files have to have a delimiter and a quotechar. the module does that by default. If you do not use it you have to put hem yourself

Comment: Im sorry but could you explain how to do that? Im a beginner at coding and really bad at it so if you would help me that would be great

Comment: A CSV file is a list of data separated by commas and \n (next line characters - the result of what happens when you press enter while writing a text). For exampleif you opened a csv file in a text editor a row would look like this : Bob Smith,bob@example.com,123-456-7890,123 Fake Street\n. Your data have to be written in the same way

Comment: So how do I implement that into my code?

Comment: If you show me the actual text that you want to write ( the output of `print(Deaths +"\n")` ) I will be able to help you more

Comment: Is there anywhere I could chat better with you? It says that is what it recomends and I could show you there.

Comment: Currently searching how can we initiate a chat in stack overflow

Comment: Do you have like a snap or something. I could delete this comment after so nobody would see.

Comment: Show part of `print(Deaths +"\n")` . I think that after it I will be able to post a solution

Comment: I cant put an image. All it says is 1,342,594 in the terminal

Comment: the thing is that the number will change. Also, I need to refresh the code too. Like I need to put something in that will rerun it. Is there anywhere we could talk tho?

Comment: the domain after @ ?

Comment: Is that good? I just deleted the part with my email

Comment: yes I just have sent you one

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils

html = req.get('https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
containers = doc.selects('div.callout').contains('Total Deaths')
out_filename = "usacovid_deaths.csv"
rows = []
rows.append(["count","new cases"])
spans = containers[0].spans
rows.append([spans[0].text,spans[1].text])
utils.save2csv(out_filename,rows)
```

Reslut:

```
count,new cases
"80,820","1,064 New Deaths*"
```

Comment: thank you so much. Do you think you could help me with some more questions? Could email you?

Comment: whats your email?

Comment: I sent emailed you.